# Prevent automatic windows auth signin after signing out using asp.net core cookie authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, cookie-authentication

I am trying to compute and cache claims for windows users using cookie authentication as the default scheme. Below is the account controller I am using for this purpose.

```
[Route("account"), AllowAnonymous]
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet, Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var windowsAuthenticationScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(windowsAuthenticationScheme);
        if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
        {
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(windowsAuthenticationScheme);
            // add claims

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return Challenge(windowsAuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("logout")]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        // both should have similar effect as cookie authentication is the default scheme
        // await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

This works quite well while signing in. However, the signout process does not seem to work quite well. After I generate a HTTP POST from my browser for the route `/account/logout`, the cookie is cleared correctly in browser.

However, on a refresh, it authenticates the user automatically, without hitting the login endpoint. Deleting the cookie explicitly using `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");` also does not help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Windows Authentication works differently: It is something that is enforced very early in the server, the application doesn't actually get to control it (that's why you enable it in IIS and it just works). With Windows authentication, the credentials are passed on every request to the application. You cannot really sign out of it.

Comment: It's a pity that it is still not possible at application level.

Comment: “still not possible” – It _cannot_ work at application level because it has to happen earlier in the network stack. By the time the request reaches the application, the authenticating has to already have happened.